# VSCode remote-ssh password prompt doesn't appear

Tags: visual-studio-code

I was trying to connect my VSCode to remote machine using remote-ssh plugin. I added the host name, port and user in the .ssh config file. The problem I had was that there was no password prompt appeared hence I couldn't enter my password and the VSCode remote-ssh connection failed. I tested the connection using ssh in a terminal and it worked, which means there was no problem with the connection itself. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try to edit settings.json file. Add:

```
"remote.SSH.showLoginTerminal": true,
"remote.SSH.useLocalServer": false,
"remote.SSH.configFile": <path_to_ssh_config>
```

Comment: Password prompt is shown in Terminal tab then